# Couchbase UPDATE not updating all documents matching filter?

Tags: java, couchbase

I have a very strange situation with the following N1QL update statement:

```
update  testBucket set A1='TESTVALUE' where TONUMBER(`Respondent.Serial`) = 8

{"results": []}



select А1 from testBucket where TONUMBER(`Respondent.Serial`) = 8
```

I get tthe following (notice that not all is updated), having:

```
      {
        "A1": "ONE"
      },
      {
        "A1": "TESTVALUE"
      },

      {
        "A1": "TESTVALUE"
      },
      {
        "A1": "TESTVALUE"
      },
      {
        "A1": "TESTVALUE"
      },
      {
        "A1": "TESTVALUE"
      },
      {
        "A1": "TEST2"
      }
```

Comment: Can you update your question with your document structure? Does the same error occur if you run the update multiple times?

Comment: My document is huge - it has nearly 10000 fields.

Comment: I tried running the update a couple of times - no change.

Comment: Do you mean 10k fields in a single document? If that is the case, I would recommend you to do some remodeling first. You can use JOINS with N1QL, so you can avoid documents to be this big. Second,  have you tried to run this via your application? I would guess that you are getting some timeout or error.

Comment: I have done some testing with documents with 10,000 fields, and updates of such large documents can take significant time before the changes are visible. How much time did you allow between the 'UPDATE' statement and the 'SELECT' to view the results? As @deniswrosa said, you may want to remodel your data if such updates are frequent.

Answer (score 2):

The problem may be that you are using backticks around Respondent.Serial.

If your document structure is like this, that isn't right.

```
{
  "Respondent": {
      "Serial": "8"
  }
}
```

You should only be using the backticks if you have a single field name that includes the period, like this:

```
{
  "Respondent.Serial": "8"
}
```

Assuming you have the former document structure, try your queries without the backticks.

Comment: update  testBucket set A1='TESTVALUE' where TONUMBER(`Respondent.Serial`) = 8 AND A1 != 'TESTVALUE'; Check any errors due to  CASE Missmatch

Comment: "Respondent.Serial": "8" is my case - my field includes the period.